# DATEADD functionality in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there any DATEADD-like functionality in Cosmos DB SQL API?

Fairly new to the SQL API for Cosmos DB and am looking for a functionality that would be close to DATEADD in SQL. Is there any? I've reviewed the system functions on the MS website but couldn't find any.

SELECT count(1) 
  FROM c
 where c.composed_at < dateadd("day",-30,c.composed_at)

Comment: I think you should try ***DateTimeAdd*** in CosmosDB. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-datetimeadd?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5001664

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Functions maybe the route to take.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs

You could define an udf in your cosmos db collection.

```
function getLastMonth(){
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.setDays(-30);
    return a;
}
```

Modify your sql to :

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.composed_at < udf.getLastMonth()
```

Note: udf.getLastMonth() returns Unix time stamp , you need to match the format.

Hope it helps you.